# ¿Como hago para guardar un arreglo en la columna de un registro de base de datos, usando PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera

pero en la bd me guarda "array" y no el arreglo, me pueden ayudar por favor.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="getmapa.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <?php include("conexion.php"); 
      $link=conectar();
    ?>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Nuevo viaje</title>



  </head>
  <body >
  <?php include("head.php");?>
    <div class="container contedor">
    <div class="titulo-contenedor">Nuevo viaje</div>
      <div class="container-int">
        <form class="container-int" action="guardarviaje.php" method="post">
<select class="refor selectpicker" multiple name="paradas[]" multiple data-actions-box="true">
<?php
      $consulta = "SELECT * FROM wck_parada ORDER BY id";
      $ejecutar = mysql_query($consulta, $link);
      while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($ejecutar)) {
        $id = $fila['id'];
        $nombre = $fila['nombre'];      
    ?>
<option type="checkbox" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($id); ?>" name="nombre"><?php echo utf8_encode($nombre); ?><br></option>
<?php }
          mysql_close();
          ?>
</select>
</form>

$paradas=$_POST['paradas'];

mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");


mysql_query("insert into wck_viaje(paradas)values('$paradas')", $link);

          </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hagamos esto simple, el desarrollo no es para complicarnos.
en el front se hace de esta forma:

en el backend recibes el dato por metodo POST  de la siguiente manera, si lo quieres separar por comas es:

```html
$idbd = implode(', ', $_POST['id']);
```

y guardas en la bd con un

```html
 mysql_query("insert into tabla(id)values("$id");
```

y listo para guardarlo sin comillas

Comment: para guardar ten en cueneta el $iddb como variable

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo en cuenta esta linea

```
insert into wck_viaje(paradas)values('$paradas')
```

Pudo asumir que deseas guardar todo el arreglo en un solo registro, por tanto "la solución mas practica" basada en tu estructura de base de datos es serializar el dato puedes usar bien sea:

Solución usando **json_encode**

```
$dato = json_encode($paradas);
mysql_query("insert into wck_viaje(paradas)values('$dato')", $link);
```

Solución usando **serialize**

```
$dato = serialize($paradas);
mysql_query("insert into wck_viaje(paradas)values('$dato')", $link);
```

Los métodos expuestos anteriormente no hacen mas que codificar una estructura en forma de cadena, una vez así es fácil insertarlos como valor en el campo de un registro. Aunque particularmente para guardar un simple arreglo mejor utilizaría `json_encode`, puesto que el propósito de `serialize` es el almacenamiento de valores en PHP sin perder su tipo y estructura, por ejemplo cuando quieres guardar un objeto de conexión a base de datos.

Ahora bien cuando desees recuperar la información, deberás aplicar el proceso inverso usando `json_decode` o `unserialize` para los respectivos casos.

**PD:** «Algunas recomendaciones»

- No deberías usar la API mysql en su lugar ensaya con mysqli ó PDO, esta ultima te permite usar otros motores de bases de datos como Postgres, firebird, etc.

  > Esta extensión está obsoleta a partir de PHP 5.5.0, por lo que ha sido
  >   eliminada a partir de PHP 7.0.0 ... http://php.net/manual/es/intro.mysql.php
- Deberías replantear un poco el diseño de tu base de datos no veo muy claro como relacionas la tabla `wck_viaje` y ademas no me parece muy optimo el diseño en general.

Comment: Muchas gracias NekoOs, me funciono como quería.